# Custom Keybindings for Ipython terminal

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, ipython, key-bindings

Is it possible to define custom keybindings and/or desactivate the default ones for Ipython terminal interface?

For example, I have bound <kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> to move left and right in my terminal by configuring the ~/.inputrc file (Linux), but when using Ipython terminal, <kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> is captured before and actually clears the screen.

So my questions are:

1) Is it possible to desactivate some keybindings of Ipython

2) Even better, is it possible to totally configure Ipython keymap?

Comment: Yep, you can set `InteractiveShell.readline_parse_and_bind` in a config file (default value is [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/rel-3.1.0/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py#L399)). It also uses `.inputrc`, but things in that config value take precendence, and Ctrl-L is in there by default.

Comment: Want to make an actual reply so I can mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reposting as an answer:

You can set `InteractiveShell.readline_parse_and_bind` in a config file (default value is here). It takes a list of readline config commands.

IPython also uses .inputrc, but things in that config value take precendence, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is in there by default.

Comment: This answer is out of date as of IPython 5.0, which has dropped `readline` in favor of Python-based `prompt_toolkit`. My keybindings no longer work. I am not sure how to transition them to `prompt_toolkit`.

Comment: See here for how to customise it in IPython 5: http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config/details.html#keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

For newer versions of IPython, [TerminalInteractiveShell.shortcuts](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html#configtrait-TerminalInteractiveShell.shortcuts) handles adds/changes to keybinds.

For example, to add `C-]` in addition to `End` for accepting the autocomplete suggestion, I added the following to my `ipython_config.py`:

```py
c.TerminalInteractiveShell.shortcuts = [
    {
        "command": "IPython:auto_suggest.accept_or_jump_to_end",
        "new_keys": ["c-]"],
        "create": True,
    }
]
```