# IPython backwards/forwards history search

Tags: python, ipython, readline

Too often it happens to me that I am coding a scripts in Ipython and when I want to you backwards/forwards in history I have to go through every line of the script.

[image]

It's there a key bind or more immediate way to go to the previous/next command?

I would love if something like `<up arrow>` would go by line and `<Ctrl-n>` would go by *command/script*.

Comment: `<ctrl-up>`? Which OS?

Comment: @AChampion Mac and Linux. and `<Ctrl-up>` doesn't works for me on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*It's there a key bind or more immediate way to go to the previous/next command?*

Yes, at least for Mac: **Fn + Shift + Up Arrow / Down Arrow**

*I would love if something like up arrow would go by line and Ctrl-n would go by command/script.*

If you would rather create a custom shortcut then I can only point you in the right direction: [Custom Keybindings for Ipython terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014267/custom-keybindings-for-ipython-terminal) Check out Thomas K's comment with update for iPython 5.0+.